# I lost my php-fpm.sock file from / var / run / php-fpm /

Tags: php, linux, redhat, php-7

I installed PHP 7 on Red Hat Linux server, but apparently due to running a few commands on the server to configure PHP I have the lost the `php-fpm.sock` file.

Could anyone please assist me with contents of the file?

Comment: Shouldn't that file should get created automatically when you start your `php-fpm` service?

Comment: @Chris, thanks, l finally resolved it, just added an empty .sock page with the same name

Answer (score 3):

Yes that file should be auto generated, do not create the file manually! Ensure that the service is running `service php-fpm start` If it still fails, check the permissions. Check here for help: `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` This is your main php-fpm config file. Make sure `user`, `group`, `listen.owner`, `listen.group` are set to your either **nginx** or **apache** user, depending on what web server you use. Also note that `listen` point to the actual socket file.